# How to turn a named vector into a named list, while grouping entries with the same name into one list element?

Tags: r, list, vector, data-structures

How do I produce `tmp_l` from `tmp_v` given as follows:

```
tmp_v <- c(a = 1, a = 2, a = 3, b = 2, c = 0, c = 4, a = 4)
tmp_l  <- list(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4), b = 2, c = c(0, 4))
```

`as.list` achieves half of this conversion, except each vector element is a separate list element. I wish to combine all elements with the same name into one list element:

```
> as.list(tmp_v)
$a
[1] 1

$a
[1] 2

$a
[1] 3

$b
[1] 2

$c
[1] 0

$c
[1] 4

$a
[1] 4
```

Interestingly `unlist(tmp_l)` almost provides the inverse action:

```
> unlist(tmp_l)
a1 a2 a3 a4  b c1 c2 
 1  2  3  4  2  0  4
```

Context: optimisation routines like optim require lists of parameters to be combined into one vector of parameters. Packages do this conversion and add the name of the parameter in the list to the vector of parameters. After finding the optimal parameter vector, it is sometimes desired to convert it back into the original list structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `split`ting the `vector` by the `names` of the `vector`

```
tmp_n <- split(unname(tmp_v), names(tmp_v))
identical(tmp_n, tmp_l)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to `stack` and `unstack` the vector:

```
unstack(stack(tmp_v))
## $a
## [1] 1 2 3 4
## 
## $b
## [1] 2
## 
## $c
## [1] 0 4
## 

identical(unstack(stack(tmp_v)), tmp_l)
## [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option with `sapply` is to find subsets of vector for every `unique` name.

```
sapply(unique(names(tmp_v)), function(x) unname(tmp_v[names(tmp_v) == x]))

#$a
#[1] 1 2 3 4
#
#$b
#[1] 2
#
#$c
#[1] 0 4
```